# How is this boolean expression evaluated?

Tags: c++

In C++, let the following construct :

```
template<typename ValueType>
ValueType * func(Foo * foo)
{
    Bar bar;
    return foo && typeid(foo) == typeid(ValueType) ? &static_cast<ValueType*>bar : 0;
}
```

How is the return statement evaluated? Like so?

```
if ((bar && typeid(bar)) == typeid(ValueType))
    return &static_cast<ValueType*>bar
return false;
```

Comment: You can't return a pointer to bar. It goes out of scope. Although actually I'm not sure what you are doing..

Comment: static_cast requires parentheses.

Comment: Yup, it's a fictitious example, bar wouldn't de declared in the score of func. I just have a hard time evaluating the return statement in terms of what has priority (&&, == or ?..).

Comment: @user3020233 What do you mean what has "priority"? Operator precedence?

Comment: You might want to choose a fictitious example that makes sense. I don't know, I always use extra brackets when using ? to be sure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foo && typeid(foo) == typeid(ValueType) ? &static_cast<ValueType*>bar : 0;
```

...corrected with parenthesis after the `static_cast<>`, is evaluated as...

```
(foo && (typeid(foo) == typeid(ValueType))) ? (&(static_cast<ValueType*>(bar))) : 0;
```

The precedence rules are listed [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).  Notice that the `?:` ternary operator is at precedence level 15 in this list - lower than the other operators you've used, so it defines the outer structure of the evaluation.  `&&` is at 13 - way below `==` at 9.  (I don't think these numbers are used anywhere in the Standard, but they're convenient references for pointing out things in the cppreference table).

Comment: +1 for adding those parentheses - while I wouldn't bother with `(&(static_cast<ValueType*>(bar)))` in my code, I'd *definitely* write `(foo && (typeid(foo) == typeid(ValueType))) ` for the sake of legibility here - wrapping first op of ternary in parentheses if it's complex saves much brain processing time IMO, same with complex booleans, maths or bitwise; while most OOP rules are well-known to most C/C++ programmers, it doesn't mean that unparentheses code is easy to read or comprehend, esp. @ 4am after 16 hours of coding...

Answer (score 0):

The posted answer correctly addresses *operator precedence* with this:

```
(foo && (typeid(foo) == typeid(ValueType))) ? (&(static_cast<ValueType*>(bar))) : 0;
```

That's how the expression will be *parsed* - which operands the compiler will regard as if belonging to which operator. That does however not state how the expression is *evaluated* (basically "executed"). So it does not answer the question:

> How is this boolean expression evaluated?

The expression is *evaluated* as:

- `foo` is evaluated.

  - If `false`, then `(typeid(foo) == typeid(ValueType))` will *not* get evaluated and the whole subexpression will be evaluated as `false`.
  - If `true` then `(typeid(foo) == typeid(ValueType))` will get evaluated. Both operands of the `==` will get evaluated (and overloaded operators called if applicable). If that whole expression is `true` then the result of the `&&` is also `true`.
- If the result of the previous evalution was `true`, then the 2nd operand `(&(static_cast<ValueType*>(bar)))` will get evaluated.
- Otherwise if the result of the previous evaluation was `false`, then the 3rd operand `0` will get evaluated.

Notably, the 2nd and 3rd operands of `?:` need to be of the same type. In case of pointers that means exactly the same type, although if one operand is a null pointer as in this case, the result will be of the type of the other operand. In case of arithmetic types, the 2nd and 3rd operand will get "balanced" as per the usual arithmetic conversions.

The expression `&static_cast<ValueType*>bar` is also very fishy in many ways. Apart from the missing parenthesis, you cannot cast `bar` to a pointer type and you mostly likely shouldn't be doing wild type punning between types like this either.